# NameError : name ' ' not defined

Tags: python, variables, merge

So I'm merging two documents and outputting a third file

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "summarize.py", line 124, in <module>
train_data = set(document3)
NameError: name 'document3' is not defined
```

This is what I have done:

Code:

```
     filenames = ["/home/mustafa/data/combinedfile.txt", "/home/mustafa/data/sentences.txt"]
     with open("document3", "wb") as outfile:
         for fname in filenames:
             with open(fname) as infile:
                  outfile.write(infile.read())
     train_data = set(document3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Simple, you have no variable named `document3`.

Comment: Im no pythonist, but it looks like you forgot some "" around document3 at the end

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to write into a file 
`'document3`' and you are trying to read from that file(according to your comment). If that is the case you should read that file  first and then you have to process the data. So the code will be

```
filenames = ["/home/mustafa/data/combinedfile.txt", "/home/mustafa/data/sentences.txt"]
 with open("document3", "wb") as outfile:  # here document3 is file name
     for fname in filenames:
         with open(fname) as infile:
              outfile.write(infile.read())
 train_data = set(open("document3").read().replace("\n","")) #this will read all data from document3 and stores as a set.
```

Comment: Yes, I would like that same file to be my train_data

Comment: And if i dont want it as a set but just a file?

Comment: Also when I add the changes and run the file it throws UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: It is because you are trying to write unicode data. Try using .`encode("ascii","ignore")` or else skip using replace function.

Comment: Actually all my data is text and i used dos2unix on both files to make sure the the file endings are proper

Comment: Then skip replace function

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "summarize.py", line 121, in <module>
    outfile.write(infile.read().encode("ascii","ignore"))
MemoryError

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143825/discussion-between-mani-and-silas).